# RTK Query: How to query an array of IDs and return an array of retrieved data?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am working with "Redux Toolkit Query" and run into the situation where I have an array of place ids and want to return an array of retrieved places. However, with my current setup, I am only able to query a single place, but not the entire compiled list of places.

Hooks where i call the query:

```
function ShowPlaceList() {
  const placeIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = useGetPlaceByIdQuery({
    placeID: placeIDs,
  });

  // data should be an array 
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(function (item, i) {
        return <ShowPlace {...item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Simplified Slice:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'


export const placeApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'placeApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://providePlace.co/api/v2/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getGetPlaceById: builder.query({
      query: ({placeID}) => `place/${placeID}`,
    }),
  }),
})


export const { useGetPlaceByIdQuery } = placeApi
```

I am happy for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are bound to the rules of hooks and cannot call hooks in a loop, the most natural way of doing this would be to call `useGetPlaceByIdQuery` within `ShowPlace`, not the parent component.

Comment: But is there at least any approach to fetch an array of results? In my case, it's required to have all results in place to display smth on the screen and the arguments array is coming from the memorized selector

Comment: Not at the moment, no.